# Changing aria-label for ascending and descending states on a sortable table with Jquery

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables, wai-aria

Hi I am trying to change the aria-labels on a sortable column. I am using Jquery. I can get the label to change but I don't know how to change it so that the label will change based on whether it is ascending or descending. As of now it changes the label but when you click the the arrows it defaults back to the original label coming from the datatables jquery.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

var x = $("div.masthead a:first").attr('href');
var lang = x.slice(-2);

if (lang==='fr'){
var sSearchfr = "filtre";
var sInfoEmptyfr = "Résultats 0 à 0 sur 0";
var sInfofr = "Résultats _START_ à _END_ sur _TOTAL_";
var sZeroRecordsfr = "Aucun résultat pour cette recherche. Il se peut que le nom recherché soit mal orthographié ou que le député en question n’ait présenté aucune demande de remboursement depuis deux ans";
var sInfoFilteredfr = "filtrés sur  _MAX_";
var sortdn = ": Trier les résultats par ordre croissant";
var sortup = ": Trier les résultats par ordre décroissant";
}
$('#form1\\:memberRidingList').DataTable({
     "oLanguage": {
             "sInfo": sInfofr,
          "sInfoEmpty": sInfoEmptyfr,
          "sZeroRecords": sZeroRecordsfr,
          "sInfoFiltered": sInfoFilteredfr,
          "sSearch": sSearchfr,

           "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending": sortup,
        "sSortDescending": sortdn
        }
    },
"paging":   false
} );

$("table.display tbody tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");

if (lang==='en'){

$(".dataTables_filter label").html('Filter:<input type="search" class placeholder aria-controls="form1:memberRidingList">');    //add new label 'filter' replace 'Search'

}

});
```

Should I change it based on matching the html and label name?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`language`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language) option and customize text using `aria.sortAscending` and `aria.sortDescending` properties.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   "language": {
        "aria": {
            "sortAscending":  ": Activate to sort column ascending",
            "sortDescending": ": Activate to sort column descending"
        }           
   }
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yt2mLn4b/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Hi I have to do it for a bilingual website. Right now I am using language detection and using 'if' 'else' to load the correct script. Otherwise I would use datatables. I tried it in my else but it doesn't work and breaks the table. I need to do the same thing with oLanguage on "Showing 1 to 48 of 48 entries".

Comment: This method was able to work for me on the french. However on english I had to use jquery selector and update the html through it.

Comment: @steve, why not use if..else here too,  or a simple ternary for this job?

Comment: @davidkonrad Hi David I updated the code with what I have working now. I am not sure how a 'ternary' would work? thanks